# nginx forwarder params to angular

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

How can i use nginx for get param and forwared to angular route into container ?
In my angular route i haves this:

```js
{
   path: 'version/:number/component/display/data',
   component: DisplayComponent
},
```

In my index.html i have this:

```html
<base href="./">
```

In nginx I try this:

```js
location version/(.*)/component/display/data {
     proxy_pass http://container:8080/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

I hope access to container using this url:
`http://domain.local/version/1/component/display/data?date=2020`

Is possible do this ?